# Output displayed on compiler is different from expected value. But correct value is obtained when copy-pasting this value to Excel

Tags: excel, c++14

Output displayed in the compiler is incorrect but when copied from the compiler and pasted to Ms Excel, it magically appears to become the correct output. what might be the reasons for it and how can I correct this issue.

I am solving Project Euler #2 on HackerRank. The problem demands summation of even fibonacci number under the given limit. I passed all test cases except test case 3. Going through the discussions, I realised that due to the involvement of arithmetic operations on very large numbers, it might be causing a issue. Therefore I took the given boundary condition of N = 4*10^16 and obtained a solution through my code and compared the answer with my manually calculated answer in excel.

expected answer (Excel) :

```
49597426547377700
```

whereas compiler output is (HackerRank) :

```
49597426547377738
```

Things got interesting when I copied the compiler output in excel, then I got the paste in scientific notation 4.95974E+16 . upon converting the cell from general to number type on the number tap, voila!  I got the correct expected answer.

What might be causing this and how do I deal with this?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

unsigned long prep_fibonnaci[100] =     

{

1, 1, 2, 3 ,5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 4807526976, 7778742049, 12586269025, 20365011074, 32951280099, 53316291173, 86267571272, 139583862445, 225851433717, 365435296162, 591286729879, 956722026041, 1548008755920, 2504730781961, 4052739537881, 6557470319842, 10610209857723, 17167680177565, 27777890035288, 44945570212853, 72723460248141, 117669030460994, 190392490709135, 308061521170129, 498454011879264, 806515533049393, 1304969544928650, 2111485077978050, 3416454622906700, 5527939700884750, 8944394323791460, 14472334024676200, 23416728348467600, 37889062373143900,61305790721611500

};

long T;
long N;

int main() 

{

    cin >> T;


    for (long i=0 ; i < T ; i++)
    {

      cin >> N;

      long highest_fib;
      int index;
      long sum = 0;

      for (int j = 0; j <= 82; j++) 
      {

            if (prep_fibonnaci[j] > N) 

            {
            index = j - 1;
            //cout <<"index: " << index << "\n";
            highest_fib = prep_fibonnaci[index];
            //cout <<"highest_fib: " <<highest_fib <<"\n";
            break;
            }

      }


      for (int k = 2; k <= index; k = k+3) 

      {
            sum = sum+prep_fibonnaci[k];
            //cout << "sum: " << sum << "\n";
      }


       cout << sum << "\n";

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excel may be doing some floating point conversions and losing precision. I would trust it less than the C++ code.

Comment: Wolfram alpha gets 49597426547377748, a difference of 10: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+F_%7B3%2An%7D,+1+to+27

Comment: Excel uses doubles internally, which can only represent ints up to 2^53, so it is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @BrennanVincent but my calculation done for desired output matches the excel converted value. is there some reason floating point precision by std::cout is being formatted to display the way it is displaying by approximation

Comment: @aschepler Yup, that is the correct answer I get now.

Answer (score 1):

How did you calculate your `prep_fibonacci` array? The values starting with `1304969544928650` are wrong -- I think this is your issue.

Comment: This post doesn't look much like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it.

Comment: @double-beep What? How is this not an answer? The question is why is his output wrong, the answer is because his `prep_fibonacci` precomputed array is wrong. It seems to answer the question exactly. By the way this isn't my first day on SO. I know what comments are. As you can see I had already left one on this very question which you would know if you had actually looked at it closely.

Comment: Perhaps you saw this before I edited it? It was clearly an issue of pressing enter too soon.

Comment: @BrennanVincent Ah! I see, I copied them from a website , let me correct that and get back to you and perhaps this time I will generate values myself rather than copy them from unverified sources on the internet.

Comment: The issue is not the website, I copied these values in excel sheet to remove the formatting, and then used them in the array. I think the way excel handles precision the values got changed. The value should have been 1304969544928657 but instead excel made it to be 1304969544928650

Comment: Please stop relying on Excel. It uses doubles internally, making it totally unfit for these large integer computations. I'm not really sure what you are doing with excel or what formatting you are trying to remove, but you should stop. Anyway, look at these three successive values: 498454011879264, 806515533049393, 1304969544928650 . Add those up by hand (not using Excel) and you'll see that the third one is *not* the sum of the first two. (Which you can see just by looking at the last digit)

Comment: @BrennanVincent Hey, I got the correct answer now, this  was the issue.